# Identify this component with a weight inside a cylinder

Tags: sensor, components, identification, motion

This component was pulled from a device that was used to detect movement. When I first saw this part, I thought it was an electrolytic capacitor, but upon closer inspection, I found that if I shake the part, it has a small metal weight in the end (opposite of the two wires) that rotates around. I'm guessing it is some kind of mechanical motion sensor, but I'm not sure what the technical name is. I'm interested in finding its datasheet or a similar part to use for another project.

Here are a couple of pictures of it:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Detect the movement of the device it was mounted on, or detect the movement around?

Comment: I believe to detect the movement of the device it was attached to

Comment: Then yeah, as said, it's a tilt sensor/switch. Something similar to this: http://www.chipmall.com/product/comus-international/pd6010/5998876

Comment: I know the text in the op leads us to this conclusion, but doesn't it look more like a vibration motor?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like a vibration motor.  A small electric motor with an unbalanced weight on the end of the shaft.  Apply a small voltage and it should spin and vibrate.

Looks a lot like [this one](https://www.thingbits.net/products/vibration-motor-capsule).

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it is! I also connected it to a  power supply to confirm that it does spin and vibrate. Thank you!

Comment: So, Jason, how do you explain your first statement, "*This component was pulled from a device that was used to detect movement.*"? I'm just wondering what sent you off on the wrong track?

Comment: For one it looks like a canned tilt sensor...

Comment: @Transistor it's still possible that the larger device this was pulled from detects movement. And apparently also vibrates sometimes (though that seems a little self-defeating).

Comment: @mbrig: Of course, but what was this thing? And what was the thought process?

Comment: Most DC motors will generate a voltage if you spin them. I imagine that a vibration motor hooked up to a voltage sensor could be used in reverse, as a jury-rigged movement sensor.